# How fast is water added to swimming pools?

Tags: swimming

I'm curious how much new water (not just filtered) is typically added to a swimming pool. What replacement rate would that imply for the pool as a whole? (Time to replace the whole volume of the pool). I'm sure it's different for indoor and outdoor pools, as outdoor will have a lot more evaporation.

The immediate reason for this question is that my eyes hurt this morning after swimming two hours yesterday. I'm sure it has to do with impurities in the water.

Comment: The amount of water would depend on the size of the pool.

Comment: Well, yes, it will depend on a lot of things, including that. But useful info should still exist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physical fitness. No idea where you'd post it instead though, maybe just ask your local pool manager?

Comment: More likely it has to do with the chlorine or salt water (Depending on filtration system) than impurities in the water.